# Map Values from List of Lists to Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

I have a list of lists in the following format:

```
l = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6], [7], [8,9,10]]
```

and a pandas dataframe with the following column

| Value |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 9 |

My goal is to loop through every row in the value column in the dataframe to find what list the value is in. I'd like to create a new column with the first value from the list that the value is in. The result would look something like this.

| Value | List_Val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 9 | 8 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use dictionary comprehension and `map`:

```
df['list_val'] = df['Value'].map({v:i[0] for i in l for v in i})
```

Output:

```
   Value  list_val
0      1         1
1      3         1
2      5         5
3      9         8
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10]]

df["List_Val"] = df["Value"].apply(
    lambda x: next((subl[0] for subl in l if x in subl), np.nan)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Value  List_Val
0      1         1
1      3         1
2      5         5
3      9         8
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `explode` then `map`

```
s = pd.Series(l).explode()
s.index = s.groupby(level=0).transform('first')
df['List_val'] = df['Value'].map(dict(zip(s,s.index)))
df
Out[36]: 
   Value  List_val
0      1         1
1      3         1
2      5         5
3      9         8
```